# Grails / Spring: How do you use importBeans with property a placeHolder in the spring.xml?

Tags: java, spring, grails, groovy

In my `Config.groovy`, I have a variable defined:

```
    bbws.baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/ballot-builder-ws/"
```

In my `spring/resources.groovy` I have the following:

```
importBeans "classpath:ballot-builder-client.spring.xml"
```

The `ballot-builder-client.spring.xml` contains the following property placeholder:

```
<jaxrs:client
    id="ballotBuilderWebService"
    address="${bbws.baseUrl}"
    serviceClass="com.xx.xx.xx.BallotBuilderWebService"
    inheritHeaders="true">
.....
</jaxrs:client>
```

I can't seem to get this to work. The Grails documentation says this is possible, isn't very helpful beyond that. Can someone confirm/deny this is possible? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you say you can't get it to work, what specifically are you seeing?

Comment: First, the works if I hard code the URL value. Second, I get the wrong value, or I'll get a property placeholder not resolved, or an invalid character depending on the setup. Sorry for the abstract answers, but this grails app is incredibly convoluted and there are a lot of moving pieces. I'm also very unfamiliar with Grails, so if you can instruct me what to look for I can retrieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. It *does* work! The solution was a proprietary configuration problem. Thank you to all who looked.

Comment: The code I have in the question _actually_ works. The problem was in the webservice itself! Not the jaxrs client.